# CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'

Tags: macos, conda, miniconda

Bash shell

MacOS Ventura 13.5.2 (22G91)

Miniconda (conda) v23.11.0

Attempting to get this project up and running: https://github.com/cumulo-autumn/StreamDiffusion but running into a problem at https://github.com/cumulo-autumn/StreamDiffusion?tab=readme-ov-file#step1-make-environment

```
# Runs successfully
conda create -n streamdiffusion python=3.10

# Gives the same issue
# CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'
conda activate streamdiffusion
```

If I run `conda activate bash`:

```
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin/conda
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/conda
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/conda-env
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/activate
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/deactivate
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /Users/geuis/.bash_profile
No action taken.
```

I have closed and reopened the shell several times, and also ran `source ~/.bash_profile`, but I still get the same error.

Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Default shell in macOS is `zsh` not `bash`. Try `conda init zsh`.

Comment: If you really are using Bash shell, follow up question is, "What terminal?"

Comment: @merv default MacOS terminal. Nothing different like iTerm, etc. I don't use zsh. When I `echo $SHELL` its `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @merv ironically although my shell was set to bash, I just switched over to zsh and its working as expected. Welp been meaning to switch at some point, now is as good as any other time.

Comment: Beyond digging through your `~/.bash_profile` for something problematic (e.g., script crashes before it gets to the Conda part), I can't think of any more specific suggestion. But please let me know if you want this reopened.